# Не подключается хостинг pythonanywhere discord.py

Tags: python, discord, бот, hosting, pythonanywhere

Раньше у меня был бесплатный хостинг heroku, но его сделали платным. Я хотел поставить бота на pythonanywhere но как выяснилось он не совместим с discord.py:

```
Cannot connect to host discord.com:443 ssl:default [Connect call failed ('162.159.135.232', 443)
```

Можете предложить решение проблемы или посоветовать другой хостинг?

Answer (score 2):

Бесплатный аккаунт на pythonanywhere не поддерживает апи вебсокетов дискорда, решение проблемы здесь : https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/7384/#id_post_42150
Или вы можете использовать replit.com для хостинга

Comment: Можете дать более подробную информацию по этому модулю или предложить хостинг кроме replit (часто вылетает или перезагружается)?

Comment: Облачные серверы от гугла, там на год бесплатно дают.

Comment: А ещё варианты имеются?